# Is the law of iterated expectation correctly applied here?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, bayesian

I am following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6OgXZUSNFE&t=248)
[image: exp]
It is established that:

$\mathbf E[\tilde\Theta\hat\Theta\mid X=x] = 0.$

Using the law of iterated expectations,

$\mathbf E\bigl[\mathbf E[X|Y]\bigr] = \mathbf E[X]$

it argues that

$\mathbf E[\tilde\Theta\hat\Theta] = \mathbf E[\tilde\Theta\hat\Theta\mid X=x] = 0.$

However what I deduce from the law of iterated expectation is:

$\mathbf E[\tilde\Theta\hat\Theta] = \mathbf E\bigl[\mathbf E[\tilde\Theta\hat\Theta\mid X=x]\bigr].$

Are they saying

$\mathbf E[\tilde\Theta\hat\Theta\mid X=x] = \mathbf E\bigl[\mathbf E[\tilde\Theta\hat\Theta\mid X=x]\bigr]?$

Is this a violation of the law's definition?

Comment: What is the "it" that argues that $\mathbf E[\tilde\Theta\hat\Theta] = \mathbf E[\tilde\Theta\hat\Theta\mid X=x]$? This isn't in the part that your image shows. If you show us where this is argued, more can perhaps be said. (In the present context they are of course equal, since the expectation of zero is zero, but you're right that generally another expectation would have to be formed.)

Comment: @joriki, `it` = the video in the link.

Comment: And thank you for the explanation!

Comment: I watched the video from the timestamp that you linked to to the end. It doesn't show that equation. It basically shows what you'd already shown here in the image (which, as I said, doesn't argue that $\mathbf E[\tilde\Theta\hat\Theta] = \mathbf E[\tilde\Theta\hat\Theta\mid X=x]$), and then goes on to talk about the variances. Did you intend that we skip back in the video from the point that you linked to to find this somewhere in the rest of the video? Please point out precisely where that argument is made.

Comment: @joriki, the timestamp is there to show where the screenshot comes from.

Comment: OK, I voted to close with reason "needs details or clarity". I've asked you twice now where that argument is made; if you don't provide that information, there's no way to answer the question. You can't expect us to view an entire $6$-minute video to find something instead of you stating where it is.

Comment: @joriki, you already answer my question.

Comment: In that case, you could post the answer and accept it so that the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Comment: With your permission, I will do it now.  Don't wanna plagiarize.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

$\mathbf E[\tilde\Theta\hat\Theta\mid X=x] = \mathbf E\bigl[\mathbf E[\tilde\Theta\hat\Theta\mid X=x]\bigr] = \mathbf E[0] = 0.$